# I am having trouble with my form redirecting to a specific URL based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where I am trying to redirect the user to a different URL based on the input in the text field. So if they put "string1" it will redirect them to "./string1.html" if they put "string2" it will redirect them to "./string2.html" and if they put "string3" it will redirect them to "./string3.html"

When I click on the "submit-form" button it takes me to the "./default.html" page instead of going to its corresponding page with the input from the form.

Here is the Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>redirect</title>
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='redirect_form.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--== Include CSS File Here ==-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="first">
            <center><img src="hrhclogo.png" alt="Har"></center>
            <br>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text">
                    <button id="submit-form" type="button">Go!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var urlMapping = {
                    "fiftytwenty": "https://www.google.com",
                    "fiftysixty": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                    "fiftyeighty": "https://www.gmail.com"
                }

                $("#submit-form").click(function () {
                    var input = $("input").val().trim();
                    if (urlMapping.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
                        window.location = urlMapping[input];
                    } else {
                        //if url not found, redirect to default url
                        window.location = "./default.html";
                    }
                });
            </script>

        </div>
        <!---- Including PHP File Here ---->
        <?php
            include "insert.php";
            include "autoload.php";
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why `toUpperCase()`? You should use `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: I changed it, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include JQuery in this file.

```
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

also need to be toLowercase()

Comment: I have the JQuery in the file, I just didnt include it in the code snippet. my fault. I changed it "toLowerCase()" and still the same problem.

Comment: It's working nicely in my pc. Can u clear what the actual error is showing?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.toUpperCase()` call

```js
var urlMapping = {
    "string1" : "./string1.html",
    "string2" : "./string2.html",
    "string3" : "./string3.html"
}

$("#submit-form").click(function(){
    var input = $("input").val().trim();
    if (urlMapping.hasOwnProperty(input)){
        console.log('IN REDIRECT');
        window.location = urlMapping[input];
    }
    else {
        //if url not found, redirect to default url
        window.location = "./default.html";
    }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" />
         <input type="text" />
<button id="submit-form" type="button">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I removed the "toUpperCase" call and still the same thing.

Comment: my snippet works fine, here and it redirects to the input, can you add a full example to see if there is something missing?

Comment: I posted it in an answer below. Not sure if thats how i was supposed to add it. but yeah. thank you for your help by the way. and excuse the messy code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your snippets on Codepen, the only thing I changed is `toLowerCase()` and remove the `<div>` without the closing `</div>` tag. And it runs as expected. So maybe there's some other code that affecting this code?

[Check the snippets here](https://codepen.io/Vasilenka/pen/oNgKYeR)

Check the console to see the input value when you click the button.